# Can't seem to solve this error while integrating a ML model in a Flask framework

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, pytorch

I am developing a machine learning model using CNN for brain tumor detection. I have trained a model and saved it and now want to integrate with a simple website. But I can't seem to solve this error and can't even understand why the error is occurring in the first place.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, ConcatDataset

class Dataset(object):
    """An abstract class representing a Dataset.

    All other datasets should subclass it. All subclasses should override
    ``__len__``, that provides the size of the dataset, and ``__getitem__``,
    supporting integer indexing in range from 0 to len(self) exclusive.
    """

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __add__(self, other):
        return ConcatDataset([self, other])

class MRI(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        
        tumor = []
        healthy = []
        # cv2 - It reads in BGR format by default
        for f in glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\ishan\Desktop\Ishan\Coding\Hackathon\Dataset\Yes_Data/*.jpg"):
            img = cv2.imread(f)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(128,128)) # I can add this later in the boot-camp for more adventure
            b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
            img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
            img = img.reshape((img.shape[2],img.shape[0],img.shape[1])) # otherwise the shape will be (h,w,#channels)
            tumor.append(img)

        for f in glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\ishan\Desktop\Ishan\Coding\Hackathon\Dataset\No_data/*.jpg"):
            img = cv2.imread(f)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(128,128)) 
            b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
            img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
            img = img.reshape((img.shape[2],img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
            healthy.append(img)

        # our images
        tumor = np.array(tumor,dtype=np.float32)
        healthy = np.array(healthy,dtype=np.float32)
        
        # our labels
        tumor_label = np.ones(tumor.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
        healthy_label = np.zeros(healthy.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
        
        # Concatenates
        self.images = np.concatenate((tumor, healthy), axis=0)
        self.labels = np.concatenate((tumor_label, healthy_label))
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.images.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        sample = {'image': self.images[index], 'label':self.labels[index]}
        
        return sample
    
    def normalize(self):
        self.images = self.images/255.0


class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()
        self.cnn_model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=5),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=5),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=5),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=5))
        
        self.fc_model = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=120),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Linear(in_features=84, out_features=1))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_model(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc_model(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        
        return x

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/uploads'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = {'jpg'}
path = r'C:\Users\ishan\Desktop\Ishan\Coding\Project\FinalModel.pth'

# Create an instance of the model
model_instance = CNN()

# Load your trained model
model_instance.load_state_dict(torch.load('FinalModel.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

# Set the model in evaluation mode
model_instance.eval()

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((128, 128)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
    ])
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
    return transform(image).unsqueeze(0)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return redirect(request.url)

    file = request.files['file']

    if file.filename == '':
        return redirect(request.url)

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(file_path)

        # Make predictions
        input_tensor = preprocess_image(file_path)
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(input_tensor)  # Output is a tensor
            prediction = "Tumor Detected" if output.item() > 0.5 else "No Tumor"
        return render_template('index.html', prediction=prediction, image_path=file_path)

    return redirect(request.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ishan\Desktop\Ishan\Coding\Project\app.py", line 113, in <module>
    model_instance.load_state_dict(torch.load('FinalModel.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
  File "C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2103, in load_state_dict
    raise TypeError(f"Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got {type(state_dict)}.")
TypeError: Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got <class 'type'>
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: `torch.load('FinalModel.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))` is not returning a dict of parameters.

Comment: @Karl Yes I know that but how do i solve that error?

Comment: Impossible for me to say without more information. Have you inspected the loaded object? What is it?

Comment: @Karl its a .pth file for a trained pytorch model.

Comment: Don't tell me what you think the file is. Load the file and look at what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

it seems issue with FileModel.pth file. yes, it is generated during model training it self but it shows that function

```
model_instance.load_state_dict(torch.load('FinalModel.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

only accept dictonary values, and your this file contains {type(dict)} as here in your error : :

```
File "C:\Users\ishan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2103, in load_state_dict
    raise TypeError(f"Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got {type(state_dict)}.")
TypeError: Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got <class 'type'>
```

for that you can check by printint loaded project, that it is <class='dict'> or not,

```
print(type(torch.load(....)))
```

if it is not dictonary then it may be issue with how the model is saved.
if u can provide more information about full filepath or model, it will easy to answer.